# Calculating expected value

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, exponential-distribution

Came across an interesting problem.

> You’re clearing out your garage for a garage sale, and you want to get rid of as much stuff as possible quickly. You found a dresser and decided to sell it to the first person offering 220 dollars or more. Assume offers to buy the dresser are independent exponential random variables with a mean of 150 dollars. The price is firm, and you keep taking offers until you receive one that is at least 220 dollars.

> Given you only accept offers at or above $220, how much money do you expect to get for your dresser, in terms of the probability *p* that any single offer is too low.

Is this as simple as adding 220 to the mean to get 370? If not, how else could I solve this?

Comment: To see why the simple solution *method* is wrong, consider a variant of this question where the offers follow a uniform distribution between 50 and 250 dollars.  This, too, has a mean of 150 dollars --but it implies you will never get an offer as high as 370 dollars, whence it's impossible for the expected value to be 370.  Evidently this exercise is trying to get you to use some facts about exponential distributions particularly.  (Even so, it's possible the *number* you suggest could be correct ;-).)

Comment: @whuber Would I use some sort of integral or summation?

Comment: @whuber  Maybe by integrating x150e-150x from 220 to infinity?

Comment: Search our site for ["memoryless."](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=memoryless)